# Why is it taking so long for eclipse to run my python script?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7 and just installed Eclipse and Pydev per [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=vHRRiBHI3to#start=0:00;end=12:35;autoreplay=false;showoptions=false)

Now I'm trying to run a demo script just like in the end of the video, and it is taking me 12 seconds to print 'hello world3'

My screen looks like this:

[image]

I'm at a bit of a loss. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your computer hamster-wheel-powered?

Comment: Try running it one more time.

Comment: I like that you went through the trouble of obscuring your username in the screenshot, but didn't obscure it well enough to prevent us from seeing that it's "chris"…

Comment: The reason @irrelephant's comment is a good suggestion is that it may have been, say, 11.5 seconds of Eclipse figuring out how to "build" your project, 0.4 seconds of starting the Python interpreter, and 0.1 seconds of running your code. If you run it again, that 11.5 seconds would almost completely disappear (and even the 0.4 would probably come down a bit because of caching).

Comment: @abarnert, was concerned with the company domain name

Comment: @irrelephant, after shutting down it went quickly.

Comment: Hey, when my computer's shut down, it never does anything slow either. :) (Sorry, I couldn't resist…)

Comment: Attacking his cpu speed & profile name is irrelevant to the question.  ~6s for a print("Hello world") is standard in my eclipse console.  Maybe it's scanning all workspaces?